# custom PCB shape in proteus

Tags: pcb, proteus

How can I customize board shape in Proteus ?
I've seen answers in other forums saying "use the 2D closed path" tool, but none demonstrate how exactly.
I want a hexagonal PCB, is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Proteus 8.9 and the option is the one that it shows in the picture. What you need to do is select "board edge" and then select "2D closed path" (Indicated with the red arrow) then you start from one point of the screen and you start drawing the form that you want.
[image: Here it is how it looks like]

Answer (score 1):

You can also import a DXF file onto the BoardEdge Layer.